# Is it possible to implement the Invaded Cluster Algorithm on a network of Ising spins rather than a lattice?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, spin-models, network, percolation

My main concern is how to know if a cluster has percolated the network. For a periodic square lattice it is easy to determine if the cluster percolates by looking at the size of the cluster (as given in Newman and Barkema's book Monte Carlo Methods in Statistical Physics). But are there any techniques or algorithms to can do the same for an arbitrary network?

Comment: Might [scicomp.se] be better suited for this question?

Comment: @KyleKanos probably we should just have an Ising Model Stack Exchange all its own